# Double integral problem $\iint e^{\frac{x}{x+y}}\,dx\,dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I'm trying to integrate $$\iint e^{\frac{x}{x+y}}\,dx\,dy$$ where $y \leq (1-x)$ and $0 \leq x,y \leq 1$.

I tried to define new variables as $u=x$ and $v=x+y$, but I can't solve this either. I have notice  $\int e^{\frac{1}{x}}dx$ is not elementary function. so it really confuses me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuition is correct and will form the starting point of our computations. Your integral is $\int \limits _0 ^1 \Bbb d x \int \limits _0 ^{1-x} \Bbb d y \space \Bbb e ^{\frac x {x+y}}$. Make the change of variable $v = x+y$ in the inner integral, obtaining $\int \limits _0 ^1 \Bbb d x \int \limits _x ^1 \Bbb d v \space \Bbb e ^{\frac x v}$ and thus decoupling the denominator from the numerator (previously they were coupled by having a $x$ in common). As you have noted, it is impossible to compute the inner integral, therefore change the order of integration: $\int \limits _0 ^1 \Bbb d v \int \limits _0 ^v \Bbb d x \space \Bbb e ^{\frac x v} = \int \limits _0 ^1 \Bbb d v \space v (\Bbb e - 1) = \frac {\Bbb e -1} 2$.

Comment: thanks. but something is still not sitting well in my head ... how did the (1,0) and (1,x) became (1,0) and (v,0) ?

Comment: @d_e: Read the endpoints before commuting the integrals: they tell you that $0 \le x \le v \le 1$. Now, you want to put $v$ first and $x$ second, so reread this inequality: $v$ lives between $0$ and $1$ (you need fixed endpoints for the outer integral) and then $x$ is left to live between $0$ and $v$.

Comment: sounds good. thanks.